# Displaying random items from table

Tags: python, django

I am trying to display 3 random items from my database in my product page. I have created a function in my models:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.FloatField()
    discount_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    label = models.ManyToManyField(Label, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()

    def random(self):
        count = self.aggregate(count=Count('id'))['count']
        random_index = randint(0, count - 1)
        return self.all()[random_index]

  def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("core:product", kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })
```

My views:

```
def random_items(request):
    random = Item.objects.random()

    return render(request, "product.html", {'random': random})
```

and the product page:

```
{% for item in random %}
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4 d-flex align-items-stretch ">

  <div class="card">

    <div class="view overlay ">
      <img src="{{ item.image.url }} " class="card-img-top">
    </div>


  </div>

</div>
{% endfor %}
```

class DetailView:

```
class ItemDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Item
    template_name = "product.html"
```

my urls:

```
path('product/<slug>/', ItemDetailView.as_view(), name='product'),
path('product/<slug>/', random_items, name='random')
```

I am getting no image, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order the elements by `'?'`, and then return the first three items:

```
def random_items(request):
    random = Item.objects.order_by('?')[:3]
    return render(request, "product.html", {'random': random})
```

This however can be very slow for huge tables. You can also first fetch the primary keys, select three elements, and then select these items:

```
from random import sample

def random_items(request):
    rand_pk = sample(Item.objects.values_list('pk', flat=True), 3)
    random = Item.objects.filter(pk__in=rand_pk)
    return render(request, "product.html", {'random': random})
```

or in the `DetailView`, you can include it in the context by overriding the `get_context_data`:

```
class ItemDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Item
    template_name = 'product.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context.update(random=Item.objects.order_by('?')[:3])
        return context
```

Comment: is there a way to put that order_by inside `DetailView class`? I have got a class and def that points to the same html page and I think that's the problem why its not displaying

Comment: @Menor: yes, you override the `get_object` method.

Comment: that didnt work as intended, when i click on the item and it redirects me on product page with details about the item it shows me a random one

Comment: I wanted to have like a row of 3 items below the main item with random items and now it shows me a random one as the main one

Comment: @Menor: yes of course. If you want to work with a `DetailView`, you need to use a url with its primary key. I had the idea that you wanted to render a random item.

Comment: can you check my urls? Is that the correct way? I am getting no image still

Comment: @Menor: how do you save a `slug`? How do you construct a url in the template?

Comment: I have a function in my model that gets the slug, check the post (edited)

Comment: @Menor: but in the template, you never generate the `get_absolute_url`? Furthermore you defined two url patterns that are *exactly* the same: one for the "listview", and one for the `DetailView`?

Comment: get_absolute_url is used in the page that displays all items. DetailView is used to display  all information about the item that was clicked on the main page. I wanted to display 3 random items below the main one and thats why I have created another url `random_items` just to display the random ones. What should I do?

Comment: @Menor: but what is the `slug` doing in `'product/<slug>/'` of the `random_items`?

Comment: ahh probably nothing, but then, how I can use random_items in the product that has been clicked?

Comment: @Menor: why do you need `random_items` when you *click* a product. Shouldn't it then go to the detail page? So the *first* url (not the second)?

Comment: yes it goes to the detail page using `class ItemDetailView(DetailView):`. Can I pass `random = Item.objects.order_by('?')[:3]` inside that class?

Comment: @Menor: yes, you just include it in the `get_context_data`.